# How to get column names (Tags) of influxDB with curl statement?

Tags: sql, database, curl, influxdb

To get column names (I think it is called "tags" in InfluxDB) **and** also the values I use the following syntax:

```
curl -G "http://myinfluxdb.com:123/query?u=admin&p=123" --data-urlencode "db=dbname" --data-urlencode "q=select * from xy where "articlenumber"=~ /12345678/ and time>='2021-10-30T10:00:00Z' and time<='2021-10-30T11:00:00Z'" --data-urlencode "-format='csv' -precision=rfc3339" > test.txt
```

Then the data is exported to test.txt.
How to get only the "column names"/tags (which were used in this timeframe)?

Answer (score 0):

With InfluxQL you can use [SHOW TAG VALUES](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-schema/#show-tag-values) to get this.

With Flux you can use [schema.tagValues](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/influxdata/influxdb/schema/tagvalues/)